# I don't see the message JMS queue sent from Spring Boot to ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I am doing a development to send a message to ActiveMQ Artemis Version 2.16.0. So I did a concept test. When the message is sent from Spring all works well, but when I try search the message in ActiveMQ Artemis in the producer section I don't see neither message.

```java
@RestController
public class RestApiController {
    
    @Autowired
    ArtemisProducer producer;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/produce")
    public String produce(@RequestParam("msg")String msg){
        producer.send(msg);
        return "Done";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/produce",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String produce(@RequestBody  Person p){
        producer.send(p);
        return "Send Person Done" + p.toString();
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@EnableJms
public class ArtemisProducer {
    @Autowired
     JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    @Value("${jms.queue.destination}")
    String destinationQueue;
    
    public void send(String msg){
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, msg);
    }
    public void send(Person p){
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, p);
    }
}
```

`application.properties`:

```
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=localhost
spring.artemis.port=61616
spring.artemis.user=myuser
spring.artemis.password=otherpassword
jms.queue.destination=activemq.artemis-0526a0b16204:DLQ
```

I also tried using `jms.queue.destination=DLQ`, but the behavior was the same.

[image]
[image]

Result in ActiveMQ Artemis web console:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you [activate the logging plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/broker-plugins.html#using-the-loggingactivemqserverplugin) in `broker.xml`, send another message, and then add the logging to the question? Be sure to set `LOG_ALL_EVENTS` to `true`.

Comment: Yes, I used the camel configuration to do it.

Comment: You used the Camel configuration to do _what_ exactly? How is Camel involved here? You haven't mentioned Camel up to this point.